# Svn Commit hangs for an infinite time.How to resolve this issue

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, post-commit, post-commit-hook, svnsync

I performed following steps to implement the process of automatic mirroring in svn (relaying master commits to slave):

1. Firstly I ran `svnsync init` command to initialize the both master and slave repositories
2. Now I created `post-commit.ba`t and `post-revprop-change.bat` on the master side and `prev-revprop-change.bat` on the slave side inside the hooks directory.
3. Now on commiting my changes from the master side using eclipse the commit hangs for an infinite amount of time without any success.
4. The commands I am running in `post-commit.bat` and `post-revprop-change.bat` are:

   `svnsync sync https://TestPcWin8pro.rcik3.domain.local/svn/testrcirepo/`

   and

   `svnsync copy-revprops https://TestPcWin8pro.rcik3.domain.local/svn/testrcirepo/`

Please check the commands and suggest why the commit hangs while committing from Eclipse (using Subclipse plugin).

Comment: Do you see any activity on the server you're syncing to? Are you specifying the full path to `svnsync.exe` in your scripts? Hook scripts execute in an empty environment, including `%PATH% being empty or nearly empty, so you have to specify the full path to EXEs.

Comment: Yes I have figured out that hang caused by the commit is occurring within the call to svnsync.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see a couple of issues with your current replication configuration.

- As far as I guess, your VisualSVN Server instance is configured to use some untrusted certificate (self-signed certificate, is it?). In such case you have to add the following options to the command-line you run in both hook scripts:

  `--trust-server-cert --non-interactive`

  These options will force Subversion client to accepts the certificate without interactive prompt.
- You don't specify any authentication-related options in these command-lines. Make sure to add valid password and username options:

  `--username <USERNAME> --password <SUPERSECRET> --no-auth-cache`